# Is there an example of usage of weka JSONLoader?

Tags: java, weka

I'm using the GUI program, weka knowledge explorer. to setup my pipeline for training a classification model. Here's what a small part of my data looks like. The only attribute would be the value from text. Since it's supervised learning, I have a label / category for each tweet / document there.

```
[
  {
    "id": 8.7361726140328e+17,
    "text": "The Joki's on you! Unless you take advantage of 25% off Scarlet Court Chests - on sale now! https:\/\/t.co\/vc1ttPxJWm",
    "category": [
      "dont_care"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 8.7329941695388e+17,
    "text": "Don't be a drag - dress like a queen! Scarlet Court Chest Rolls are 25% off! https:\/\/t.co\/O0Ig5bEZdD",
    "category": [
      "dont_care"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 8.7328034547452e+17,
    "text": "Join @Inukii and @MezmoreyezTV for Top 5 Console Plays! https:\/\/t.co\/3JmreXSTWp",
    "category": [
      "dont_care"
    ]
  }
]
```

The exception I'm getting in the logs

```
11:16:12: [Low] FlowRunner$1697181913|FlowRunner: Launching start point: JSONLoader
11:16:12: [Basic] JSONLoader$17081058|Loading /home/j/_Github-Projects/GameMediaBot/SmiteGame_classified_data.json
11:16:12: [ERROR] JSONLoader$17081058|java.lang.Exception: Can't recover from previous error(s)
weka.core.WekaException: java.lang.Exception: Can't recover from previous error(s)
    at weka.knowledgeflow.steps.Loader.start(Loader.java:178)
    at weka.knowledgeflow.StepManagerImpl.startStep(StepManagerImpl.java:1035)
    at weka.knowledgeflow.BaseExecutionEnvironment$3.run(BaseExecutionEnvironment.java:440)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.Exception: Can't recover from previous error(s)
    at weka.core.converters.JSONLoader.getStructure(JSONLoader.java:242)
    at weka.core.converters.JSONLoader.getDataSet(JSONLoader.java:267)
    at weka.knowledgeflow.steps.Loader.start(Loader.java:172)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Can't recover from previous error(s)
    at java_cup.runtime.lr_parser.report_fatal_error(lr_parser.java:392)
    at java_cup.runtime.lr_parser.unrecovered_syntax_error(lr_parser.java:539)
    at java_cup.runtime.lr_parser.parse(lr_parser.java:731)
    at weka.core.json.JSONNode.read(JSONNode.java:634)
    at weka.core.converters.JSONLoader.getStructure(JSONLoader.java:234)
    ... 9 more

11:16:12: [Low] JSONLoader$17081058|Interrupted
```

My Pipeline:

[image: My pipeline]

Comment: I think it's actually pointless to have a threshHoldData transition from The PerformanceEval to the PerformanceChart if RandomForest doesn't provide that info.

Answer (score 0):

Anyways, I just wrote a script to convert my data (json) to arff. Not sure what the conventions are for determining attributes for text data. I just used the top 40 most frequent words of the categories of tweets I do care about. I added an attribute at the end called class which is like an enum which seems to be the convention for training models like this.

see the code on github or the same code here on SO  https://github.com/jtara1/GameMediaBot/blob/master/transform_to_arff.py

```
import re
import json
from os.path import join, dirname, abspath, basename
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import arff
import click


@click.command()
@click.argument('file')
@click.option('--dont-care-category',
              type=click.STRING,
              default='dont_care')
@click.option('-a',
              type=click.INT,
              default=40,
              help='Number of attributes. Attrs are the most frequent words '
                   'in the text of the target category')
def transform(file, dont_care_category, a):
    """input example
    [ {id: 123, text: "this is text body", category: ["dont_care"]} ]
    output example
    @relation game_media_bot

    @attribute

    :return:
    """
    classes = set()
    data = json.load(open(file, 'r'))

    master_vector = Counter()

    for tweet in data:
        classes.add(tweet['category'][0])
        if tweet['category'][0] != dont_care_category:
            master_vector += get_word_vector(tweet)

    print(master_vector)

    # most common words in the text of the target category
    attrs = [(word, 'INTEGER') for word, _ in master_vector.most_common(a)]
    attrs.append(('class', [value for value in classes]))

    arff_data = {
        'attributes': attrs,
        'data': [],
        'description': '',
        'relation': '{}'.format(dont_care_category)
    }

    for tweet in data:
        word_vector = get_word_vector(tweet)
        tweet_data = [word_vector[attr[0]] for attr in attrs[:-1]]
        tweet_data.append(tweet['category'][0])
        arff_data['data'].append(tweet_data)

    out_file = file.replace('.json', '.arff')
    data = arff.dumps(arff_data)
    with open(out_file, 'w') as f:
        f.write(data)


def get_word_vector(tweet):
    stop_words = stopwords.words('english')
    stop_words += ['!', ':', ',', '-', 'https', '/', '\u2026', "'s", "n't",
                   '#', '.', ';', ')', '(', "'re", '&', '?', '%', '@', "'",
                   '...']

    uri = re.compile(r'(https)?:?//t\.co/.*')

    # remove whitespace characters and put each word in a list
    words = word_tokenize(tweet['text'])

    # make each word lowercase
    words = [word.lower() for word in words]

    words = list(
        filter(
            lambda word: word not in stop_words and not uri.match(word),
            words
        )
    )

    return Counter(words)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    transform()
```